# Lock Opportunity Products after closing Opportunity

Tags: trigger, validation

After we close an opportunity we start charging the customer every month. We do not want anyone after the closure of an opportunity to be able to add more Opportunity products.

I set a new field called OpportunityProductsCounter__c which increments every time a new Opportunity product has been added. Moreover, I added a trigger that checks whether OpportunityProductsCounter__c increments after the opportunity is closed.

Is there any other more elegant/built-in way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any custom field or trigger for this use case.

You just simply write a validation rule on Opportunity object.

Basically, when Opportunity Product is getting added then Amount is calculated and reflected based on summation of all line items.

So, in the validation rule, verify StageName = "Closed Won" and stop editing amount field and throw the error.